# Proof of Hilbert transform of a real function $x(t)$ is generally a complex function

Tags: hilbert-transform, proof

I am looking for a formal proof of the result:

The Hilbert Transform of a real signal $x(t)$ is generally a complex signal. Can this be proven and if so how? Thank you.

Comment: That would be be difficult to proof since it's not true. The Hilbert Transform of a real signal is definitely real as well. You might confuse this with the analytical signal, which is indeed complex and where the real and imaginary part are a Hilbert Transform pair.

Comment: A possible reason for this confusion is the 'hilbert’ function in MATLAB and Python returns the complex analytic signal not the real Hilbert transform.

Comment: I see. Since Hilbert transform is simply a convolution, a real-valued input must map to an output in a real domain. Apologies for the confusion.